# implementing client with custom xml protocol without definition or schema

Tags: java, xml, web-services

I have a boring task to implement client side of xml based protocol. The problem is that there is no schema, no wsdl, just examples.

In such situation, is it possible to eliminate "code-monkey" work -- maybe annotate this examples somehow, or generate schema for them, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Spring support for XML mapping or go directly to JAXB or CASTOR.

Spring http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/oxm.html
Castor http://www.castor.org/xml-mapping.html